# Dropbox core or sync API

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to display all files and folders containing in **Dropbox**. Also user should be able to view, update and delete files or folders of dropbox.

for this which **Dropbox API** I need to use?

whether it should be **Core API** or **Sync API**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, and the functionality listed, the Sync API is recommended:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync

The Sync API is easier to implement and does a lot of the work for you. However, note that it doesn't support Full Dropbox access:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions

So, if you need Full Dropbox access, or any other functionality/platform support not provided by the Sync API, then you'll need to use the Core API

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core